# A little bit of If statements, some html investigating, and the webbrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, screen-scraping

I have a code that retrieves all the "place names" and all the "addresses" separately in this link:

http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si-geo/1/sh/Ottawa,+ON

I need to modify my code so that it will only retrieve the `placename` and `address` if

```
<div class="address""> is not found within <div class="listingDetail"">
```

`class="address"` is the address of the location, `class="listingDetail"` is the parent, or container. Some screenshots, please view them for better understanding:

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/67moog.png]

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/289f7n.png]

Comment: There's no code, and no actual question !!

Comment: Huh? Why do you need the code to answer my question. It uses the htmlagilitypack, so theres no point posting it unless someone knows of a method within htmlagilitypack. I'll post the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript use:

```
var addresses = Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('listingDetail'), function(listingDetail){  
   return listingDetail.getElementsByClassName('address');  
 });
```